# Incident edges on a node in networkx

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

Any help with this question is appreciated.

How do i get the incident edges on a node in a graph using networkx? I have tried searching for it in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Graph.edges()](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.edges.html#networkx.Graph.edges) method with the node as the parameter.

```
>>> G = nx.Graph()   # or DiGraph, MultiGraph, MultiDiGraph, etc
>>> nx.add_path(G, [0,1,2,3])
>>> G.edges
EdgeView([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)])
>>> G.edges(0)
EdgeDataView([(0, 1)])
>>> list(G.edges(0))
[(0, 1)]
```

Edit 2020-09-10: Updated answer for networkx 2.x

Comment: What if the graph is a digraph?

Comment: edges() works for DiGraphs too. There are also [in_edges() and out_edges()](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/classes.digraph.html#iterating-over-nodes-and-edges) if you only need incoming or outgoing edges.

Comment: not exactly. edges() on DiGraphs is equivalent to out_edges()

Comment: @miles82 your doc links are broken

Comment: @miles82 still broken

Comment: @miles82 the doc link in the comment (`in_edges() and out_edges()`)

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC comments can't be edited, so here's the updated link for [in_edges() and out_edges()](https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/classes.digraph.html#iterating-over-nodes-and-edges)

Comment: Link update for networkx 2.x [in_edges and out_edges](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html#reporting-nodes-edges-and-neighbors)